# How to install WSO2 products (ESB, AS, BPEL, IS) on a single Carbon platform?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I was able to install Carbon 4.0.1 with ESB and AS features installed.

However, when I try to install Identity Server and BPEL, there is an error because the Carbon core is not the same. I think there are not compatible with Carbon 4 yet.

Is there still a way to install these two products on Carbon 4.0.1?

If not and I have to install Identity Server and BPEL separately, will I encounter compatibility issues?

Answer (score 1):

BPEL and Identity features for the new carbon version will be released soon under 4.0.2 release very soon. You need to use older carbon version 3.2.3 and install features using [this p2 repo](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.3/features/).If you are going to use BPEL and IS separately installed it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the Offset parameter in $CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml file in order to setup multiple wso2 products on the same server. For example if you want to setup ESB, BPS and IS you have to modify the installation for each of the product and specify a different offset.

Currently, we cannot configure multiple wso2 products on the same carbon platform. You can install multiple products on the same server but each of them will run in their own carbon environment.